# I want Regex validate mobile and phone number in given format

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I want user can only enter mobile/phone number in given format.

+1234567891 > when + is used exact after plus user cannot enter 0 or 00 and also if + is used after + only 10 to 14 digits are allowed.

01234567891 > when user enter single 0 then user must enter 10 digits only after 0.

00123456789 > when user enter double 00 then after that user cannot enter 3rd 0 exact after double 00 and also user must enter 10 to 14 digits after double 00.

My code is this any one can help me please?

```
string mob = txtmobile.Text.Trim();
Regex plus = new Regex("^[+]?<!(0|00)[0-9]{10,14}$");
Regex zero = new Regex("^[0]{1}[0-9]{10}$");
Regex zeroes = new Regex("^[0]{2}[^0][0-9]{10,14}$");

        if (!plus.IsMatch(mob))
        {
            if (!zero.IsMatch(mob))
            {
                if (!zeroes.IsMatch(mob))
                {
                    lblmobile.Text = "*Mobile number must be correct format";
                    lblmobile.Visible = true;
                    flg = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common problem with your patterns is that is that they allow zeroes to be entered in all cases.
Let's take the example of `^[+]?<!(0|00)[0-9]{10,14}$` - you're telling the engine this:

- match the "+" sign
- assert that immediately there isn't a zero or double zero
- match 10 to 14 digits *including* zero

You need to change the patterns this way:

- for **plus** rule: `^[+][1-9][0-9]{9,13}$`; this translates to: "match plus sign, a digit between 1 and 9 after and 9 to 13 digits between 0 and 9"
- for **zero** rule: `^0[1-9][0-9]{9}$`
- for **zeroes** rule: `^00[1-9][0-9]{9,13}$`

By the way, the example for **zeroes** rule is invalid; there are only 9 digits after `00`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\+0[0-9]{9}|\+0[1-9][0-9]{12}|0[1-9][0-9]{8}|00[1-9][0-9]{9}|00[1-9][0-9]{13}`.

Or this: `\+0\d{9}|\+0[1-9]\d{12}|0[1-9]\d{8}|00[1-9]\d{9}|00[1-9]\d{13}`